# How to add a private method in the API that checks if a Customer exists before editing or deleting an item

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I tried looking for a method that could help with this but I could not find it.

```
routes.MapDelete("/api/Customer/{id}", async (int CustomerID, EcoPowerContext ) =>
    {
      if (await db.Customer.FindAsync(CustomerID) is Customer customer)
           {
              db.Customer.Remove(customer);
               await db.SaveChangesAsync();
               return Results.Ok(customer);
           }

           return Results.NotFound();
       })
       .WithName("DeleteCustomer")
       .Produces<Customer>(StatusCodes.Status200OK)
       .Produces(StatusCodes.Status404NotFound);
```

Comment: is the code failing? how is it failing? it is not clear to me what the problem is.  Also you might be better off creating controllers with actions rather than using the endpoint route builder extensions like that.

Comment: Any errors in your IDE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has a syntax error where you didn't declare the `db` parameter

Here is a modified code. Note where I added the parameter name after the type in `EcoPowerContext db`

```
routes.MapDelete("/api/Customer/{id}", async (int CustomerID, EcoPowerContext db) =>
    {
        if (await db.Customer.FindAsync(CustomerID) is Customer customer)
        {
            db.Customer.Remove(customer);
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();
            return Results.Ok(customer);
        }

        return Results.NotFound();
    })
    .WithName("DeleteCustomer")
    .Produces<Customer>(StatusCodes.Status200OK)
    .Produces(StatusCodes.Status404NotFound);
}
```

Other than that your code looks fine, and if it's failing after fixing the syntax error, you would need to provide more information to get help. For example is it failing at build or in runtime, what error are you getting if any, etc.